# expected a value of type 'iterable<dynamic>', but got one of type 'null'

Tags: flutter, list, api, dart

### The error in this line in recipe.api.dart:

```
for (var i in data['feed']) {
  _temp.add(i['content']['details']);
}
```

## recipe.api.dart file

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:food_recipe/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class RecipeApi {
  static Future<List<Recipe>> getRecipe() async {
var uri = Uri.https('yummly2.p.rapidapi.com', '/feeds/list',
    {"limit": "18", "start": "0", "tag": "list.recipe.popular"});

    final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "YOUR API KEY FROM YUMMLY API",
  "x-rapidapi-host": "yummly2.p.rapidapi.com",
  "useQueryString": "true"
});

Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
List _temp = [];

for (var i in data['feed']) {
  _temp.add(i['content']['details']);
}

return Recipe.recipesFromSnapshot(_temp);
  }
}
```

## recipe file

```
class Recipe {
  final String name;
  final String images;
  final double rating;
  final String totalTime;

  Recipe({this.name, this.images, this.rating, this.totalTime});

  factory Recipe.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Recipe(
        name: json['name'] as String,
        images: json['images'][0]['hostedLargeUrl'] as String,
        rating: json['rating'] as double,
        totalTime: json['totalTime'] as String);
  }

  static List<Recipe> recipesFromSnapshot(List snapshot) {
    return snapshot.map((data) {
      return Recipe.fromJson(data);
}).toList();
  }

  @override
  String toString(){
    return 'Recipe {name: $name, image: $images, rating: $rating, totalTime: $totalTime}';
  }
}
```

Comment: kindly provide code instead of adding image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)